# Request with surge_confirmation_id and surged price always response with 409 fare_expired error

Tags: uber-api

During last few weeks my app can't request any **surged** `request`.

I send initial request:

```
{
  start_latitude: xx.xxxxx,
  start_longitude: xx.xxxxx
}
```

Receive `surge` error with `surge_confirmation_id`.

Send another request:

```
{
  start_latitude: xx.xxxxx,
  start_longitude: xx.xxxxx,
  surge_confirmation_id: yyyyy-xxxxx-kkkkk-aaaaa
}
```

And always receive 409 `fare_expired`.

I sent request with `product_id` and other properties specified and tried a request with only start location and `surge_confirmation_id`.

Without `surge` API works as expected and I'm able to request a ride.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a bug which is now resolved.

Comment: is there a way to discover if the bug is fixed?